# Split list of strings into two separate lists based on comma

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list like this

```
[
    'agronomy salenrollment services,3',
    'online account manager,1',
    'game day manager,15',
    'leader biologist,16'
]
```

How I can separate numbers and make 2 different list?

output:

```
l1 = [
    'agronomy salenrollment services',
    'online account manager',
    'game day manager',
    'leader biologist'
]

l2 = [3, 1, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using a *generator expression* with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to achieve this as:

```
my_list = [
    'agronomy salenrollment services,3',
    'online account manager,1',
    'game day manager,15',
    'leader biologist,16'
]

l1, l2 = zip(*(s.split(',') for s in my_list))
```

where `l1` and `l2` will hold:

```
>>> l1
('agronomy salenrollment services', 'online account manager', 'game day manager', 'leader biologist')

>>> l2
('3', '1', '15', '16')
```

Note: `l1` and `l2` are of type [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) in above example instead of [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). If it is must for you to have these as list, then you can type-cast them to list using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as:

```
l1, l2 = map(list, zip(*(s.split(',') for s in my_list)))
#             ^ To type-cast to `list`
```

In the above solutions, `l2` is holding value as string of numbers. You can **use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)** again on `l2` **to type-cast all the elements in the list to `int` type**. For example:

```
l2 = list(map(int, l2))
# where `l2` will now hold:
#     [3, 1, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple - loop through each item in the list and split it on the `","`:

```py
original_list = ['agronomy salenrollment services,3', 
 'online account manager,1',
 'game day manager,15',
 'leader biologist,16']

l1 = [] # all strings
l2 = [] # all numbers

for item in original_list:
    split = item.split(",") # split on commas in string
    l1.append(split[0]) # add string to l1
    l2.append(int(split[1])) # add string as integer to l2
```

Or, using list comprehension: (Note that this solution will loop through the list twice, so if you want to save time, use the single for loop).

```py
l1 = [item.split(",")[0] for item in original_list]
l2 = [item.split(",")[1] for item in original_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

map returns a map class.  The splitString return a tuple with two string elements.  The map class can be iterated and the list of tuples unpacked and appended to the two lists.

```
list1=[
    'agronomy salenrollment services,3',
    'online account manager,1',
    'game day manager,15',
    'leader biologist,16'
]

def splitString(paramString):
    a,b=paramString.split(",") 
    return a,b

result=map(splitString,list1)

list1=[]
list2=[]

[(list1.append(item[0]), list2.append(item[1])) for item in result]

print(list1,list2)

output:

['agronomy salenrollment services', 'online account manager', 'game day manager', 'leader biologist'] 
['3', '1', '15', '16']
```